# How do I iterate through this JSON object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, object, loops

I have a JSON object which is generated by PHP. It's an object with a set of dates. It has the timeStamp and then a formatted version of the date. How would I iterate through this in jQuery?

```js
{
  "dates":[
    {
      "timeStamp": 1317596400,
      "formattedDate": "Mon 03 October 2011"
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": 1317682800,
      "formattedDate": "Tue 04 October 2011"
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": 1317855600,
      "formattedDate": "Thu 06 October 2011"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried:

```js
for (var i in data) { 
  alert(data.dates[i].timeStamp); 
};

for (var i in data) { 
  alert(data[i].dates.timeStamp); 
};
```

and

```js
for (var i in data) { 
  alert(data.dates.timeStamp[i]); 
};
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code for posterity, this is a good example.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as a `jquery` one, you should use [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) because it's jquery's iterator function:

```
$.each(data.dates, function(index, element) {
    alert(element.timeStamp); 
});
```

If you want to stick to the [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax (which i see you've tried), a solution might be :

```
for(var key in data.dates) {
     alert(data.dates[key].timeStamp); 
}
```

But beware that the `for in` syntax may do more than you think it does: it iterates over the properties inherited from the prototype too, so it might be usefull to make sure you iterate only on the object instance properties:

```
for(var key in data.dates) {
    // if it's not something from the prototype
    if(data.dates.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(data.dates[key].timeStamp); 
    }
}
```

**update**
Another elegant way is to use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method that returns an array containing all the keys in the targeted object to iterate over all the object's properties:

```
for(var i=0, keys=Object.keys(data.dates), l=keys.length; i<l; i++) {
    alert(data.dates[i].timeStamp);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I decided to stick with the for in syntax. Just something I'm more familiar with coming from a PHP and Java background

Comment: Shouldn't it be "i" instead of "key" in the alert?..Using 'i' worked for me

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @Ravin! It was a typo - the power of copy-paste :)

Answer (score 3):

You use [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
It looks like this:

```
$.each(data, function(n, elem) {
    // here you process your data to data loaded to lines               
});
```

Comment: $.each does not work in situations where there is no length and will just be passed over.

Comment: the OP is attempting to iterate through an array of dates, arrays have a length: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate through the json structure using [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
   alert(element.dates.timeStamp); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.each() is probably the easiest way, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

eg

```
$.each(dates, function(index, date) { alert(date.timeStamp); });
```