# Interacting with my JSON object before displaying it

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops

Hello stack overflow community,
I'm stuck at this point for a while now and even if I went through a lot of posts to try to solve it I still don't get which way would fit the best in my case to manage to display my JSON on my HTML.

First, my JSON is a varying length string, send by my php code and receive in JS via XMLHttpRequest

```
var return_data = xhr.responseText;
```

Example of JSON format:

```
"output":[
{
    "id":"13",
    "titre":"assiette servite xxx",
    "format":"dat",
    "date":"2016-09-10",
    "source":"DDT 68",
    "description":"exemple"
},
{
    "id":"16",
    "titre":"releve pollution atmospherique",
    "format":"shp",
    "date":"2014-01-05",
    "source":"agence qualite de l air",
    "description":"exemple"
},
```

I managed to display simply my JSON string with:

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
```

But here I would rather loop it in order to style it, then send it to my HTML. I've tried a lot of different loops without success
(e.g. [How do I iterate through this JSON object in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887009/how-do-i-iterate-through-this-json-object-in-jquery?newreg=a7b664198d564ac9a1c44e4e6bfbc3de))

I need to parse my string:

```
var jay = JSON.parse(return_data);
```

But then i still don't manage to work with the different entities and display for instance in my HTML

```
    <div id="status"></div>
```

id 1

titre
  format
  date

id 2

titre
  format
  date

I'm still working on it and making tests, hoping that in the meantime maybe someone could give me hints or explaining what I'm doing wrong.

example of failed test:

```
for(var i=0; i < jay.length; i++)
{
  var add = jay[i]['titre'];
}
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = add;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add two brackets to wrap your JSON from the server, that is not a correct JSON format, this is:

```
{ "output":[
       {
        "id":"13",
        "titre":"assiette servite xxx",
        "format":"dat",
        "date":"2016-09-10",
        "source":"DDT 68",
        "description":"exemple"
       },
       {
        "id":"16",
        "titre":"releve pollution atmospherique",
        "format":"shp",
        "date":"2014-01-05",
        "source":"agence qualite de l air",
        "description":"exemple"
       },
    }
```

And you have to add the output level in the loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < jay.output.length; i++)
{
  var add = jay.output[i]['titre'];
}
```

cheers

**EDIT**

```
    var add = [];
    for(var i=0; i < jay.output.length; i++)
        {
          add.push(jay.output[i]['titre']);
        }
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = add.join(', ');
```

This will display all elements separated by a comma.

Cheers

Comment: EDIT:

It works and display the "titre" but only for the first entity, not the next ones

Maybe something to add in the loop to accumulate the answers into the variable add?

Cheers.

Comment: I was working to find something similar, very good idea add.push/ add.join usage.

Thank you a lot again, you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

a more consise solution using Array.map()

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = jay.output.map(function(obj){
   return obj.titre;
}).join(', ');
```